# sqlite3.Connection object has no attribute 'enable_load_extension' on MAC

Tags: python, macos, sqlite

I implemented a Python app, which is working on Windows. 
I would like to run the app at Mac OS Sierra.

My app is working with SQLAlchemy library.

I have a class represents my db connection:

```
class DB():
'''
Represents the primary blackboard of the system.
'''

def __init__(self):
    pass

def setUp(self):
    # read config
    configInst = getConfig()
    self._date = getConfig().eval(self.__class__.__name__, "start_date")
    self.Session = sessionmaker()
    self.Session.configure(bind=self.engine)

    self.session = self.Session()

    @event.listens_for(self.engine, "connect")
    def connect(dbapi_connection, connection_rec):
            dbapi_connection.enable_load_extension(True)
    if(getConfig().eval("OperatingSystem","windows")):
                dbapi_connection.execute('SELECT load_extension("%s%s")'%(configInst.get("DB","DB_path_to_extension"),'.dll'))
    if(getConfig().eval("OperatingSystem","mac")):
        dbapi_connection.execute('SELECT load_extension("%s%s")'%(configInst.get("DB","DB_path_to_extension"),'.dylib'))

            **dbapi_connection.enable_load_extension(False)**
    if getConfig().eval(self.__class__.__name__,"dropall_on_setup"):
        Base.metadata.drop_all(self.engine)

    Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
    pass
```

When the app is running I got the next error:

```
 AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Connection' object has no attribute 'enable_load_extension'
```

I installed Anaconda for Mac OS and yet in the line with ** the app cannot get to sqlite3.py file.

I cannot link it.

Someone?

Answer (score -2):

This has been fixed, try updating anaconda!